# Access value from object(with private property) in array using php

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I want to get value from object in array. Object property has been set to private. So, I could not access the value.

I try to convert private to public using Php ReflectionClass.

VarDump of Object In Array($obj_array)

```
array(1) 
{
  [23]=>
  object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\RowDimension)#6167 (7) 
   {
    ["rowIndex":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\RowDimension":private]=>
    int(23)
    ["height":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\RowDimension":private]=>
    string(3) "7.5"
    ["zeroHeight":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\RowDimension":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["visible":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Dimension":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["outlineLevel":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Dimension":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["collapsed":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Dimension":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["xfIndex":"PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Dimension":private]=>
    NULL
    }
}
```

Code to convert private object to public

```
       foreach($obj_array as $key=>$value)
       {
         $r = new ReflectionObject($value);
         $p = $r->getProperty('height');
         $p->setAccessible(true); 
         echo $obj->height.'<br/>';
       }
```

I expect to get height value,7.5 from the object. It end up with this error.

> Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\RowDimension::$height

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `getRowHeight` function it returns the private `height` property internally. (as seen in the source of `PhpSpreadSheet`)

```
/**
 * Get Row Height.
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getRowHeight()
{
    return $this->height;
}
```

Comment: Omg, yea. thanks a lot. I put these inside the loop . It works nicely.                               
**$rowDimension   = $obj_array [$key];
$rowHeight          = $rowDimension->getRowHeight();**